# What does it mean that I must "immediately reimburse Owner for the cost of any insurance policy Owner obtains for the Apartment"?

Tags: new-york-state, residential-lease, lease, tenancy-rules

On the lease I am considering signing, it says in section 32 D:

> Tenant shall immediately reimburse Owner for the cost of any insurance
> policy Owner obtains for the Apartment, including but not limited to
> insurance for Owner’s furniture or furnishings in the Apartment.

This is part of the Standard Form of Apartment Lease issued by the Real Estate Board of New York. https://irp-cdn.multiscreensite.com/279367eb/files/uploaded/2019_FM_Lease.pdf

Does this mean that every renter in New York is subject to immediately owing their building's owner some arbitrarily large sum of money for wallpaper insurance?

Answer (score 3):

The lease requires you to get liability insurance and to insure your own property. If you don't, (para D) one of the owner's options is to get the insurance for you. Then after taking out the insurance that you are required to have, you shall reimburse owner for the insurance that he took out for your benefit. "Reimburse" means "pay back what he paid for you", which means that it is not an arbitrary sum. It is for the kinds of insurance you are required by the lease to have, and not wallpaper insurance. The only people who have to do this are renters who have leases with terms like this, not necessarily every renter in NY.

Comment: This would be, eg, insurance to cover a renter's potential liability for damage to the unit or appliances?

Comment: Any kind of liability, for damage to anything and anyone.

Comment: Doesn't "including but not limited to" imply that anything your renters' insurance policy might not cover could be bought by the owner, with the tenant made to reimburse?

Comment: Does the lease set out what types of insurance and the policy limits that you are required to obtain?

Comment: @RetiredATC Nope. It says nothing. And I was told I didn't need it. Signed anyways.